# I want to get form data in Ul li with the .map method react js

Tags: reactjs

I want the form data to be printed in Ul li with the .map method.

Form data is getting in user state, printing console also. with using map method showing error

I want the form data to be printed in Ul li with the .map method.

Form data is getting in user state, printing console also. with using map method showing error

console.log(user);

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import Bannerimg from "../../images/contact-main-banner.jpeg";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

const Contact = () => {
  const [user, setUsers] = useState({
    yourname: "",
    mobile: "",
    email: "",
    message: ""
  });

  const { yourname, mobile, email, message } = user;

  const inputChange = e => {
    //setUsers({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    setUsers({
      ...user,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

    // const { name, value } = e.target;

    // setUsers(prevval => {
    //   return {
    //     ...prevval,
    //     [name]: value
    //   };
    // });
  };

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
      .post(
        "https://sheet.best/api/sheets/3b89ec5e-3ba3-4c8f-9180-cc9352f06a19",
        user
      )
      .then(response => {
        // console.log(response);

        alert("Form successfully sent");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert("Form not  sent");
      });

    // alert(`${yourname} <br> ${mobile} <br> ${email} <br> ${message}`);
    setUsers({
      yourname: "",
      mobile: "",
      email: "",
      message: ""
    });
    console.log(user);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Contact</title>
      </Helmet>

      <section>
        <div className="banner">
          <img src={Bannerimg} className="img-fluid" />

          <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" className="breadcrumb">
            <div className="container">
              <ol className="p-0">
                <li className="breadcrumb-item">
                  <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
                  Contact us
                </li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div className="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="text-center heading-style-1">Contact us</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8">
            <form
              onSubmit={e => {
                onSubmit(e);
              }}
            >
              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Your Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="yourname"
                  value={yourname}
                  onChange={inputChange}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mobile Number</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="mobile"
                  value={mobile}
                  onChange={inputChange}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Id</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={inputChange}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Message</label>
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  rows="3"
                  name="message"
                  value={message}
                  onChange={inputChange}
                ></textarea>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-4">
            {user.map((formVal, index) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <ul>
                    <li>{formVal.yourname}</li>
                    <li>{formVal.mobile}</li>
                    <li>{formVal.email}</li>
                    <li>{formVal.message}</li>
                  </ul>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa9UP.png)

Comment: `user` is an object, not an array, so it doesn't have a `.map()` method.

Comment: Thank you @NickParsons

But, How can i print in ul li.

Comment: You don't have a list of anything in your code, so it's unclear what you want to print of a list of. If you want to print a list of users, you need to change your state to store an array of objects, not just one object. When you add a user you can append to your state array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first convert the keys of object into an array then map over it and print.

Like this:

```
<div className="col-md-4">
     <ul>
      {Object.keys(user).map(function(name){
        return <li>{name} :{ user[name]}</li>
      })}
     

     </ul>
</div>
```